# Mailserver using SMTP Relay

Tags: email-server, hmailserver

I'm using OVH as SMTP Relay. It was always working great, but now I can't send mails anymore.

If I answer to an E-Mail everything is normal. But if I write a new E-Mail it is never being received.

The logfile says that the Mail is being set normally.

```
"SMTPD" 4576    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.357"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 mysite.com ESMTP"
"SMTPD" 2724    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.357"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: EHLO mail.mysite.com"
"SMTPD" 2724    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.357"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250-mysite.com[nl]250-SIZE 20480000[nl]250-AUTH LOGIN[nl]250 HELP"
"SMTPD" 4576    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.358"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: AUTH LOGIN"
"SMTPD" 4576    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.358"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 334 VXNlcms5hbWU6"
"SMTPD" 3500    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.358"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: ZmFiaW9AbW9kc3ptvbWJpZXMuY29t"
"SMTPD" 3500    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.358"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
"SMTPD" 4576    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.358"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: ***"
"SMTPD" 4576    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.359"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 235 authenticated."
"SMTPD" 2724    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.359"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: MAIL FROM:<fabio@mysite.com> SIZE=924"
"SMTPD" 2724    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.359"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 OK"
"SMTPD" 4576    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.360"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: RCPT TO:<receiver@web.de>"
"SMTPD" 4576    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.360"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 OK"
"SMTPD" 3500    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.361"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: DATA"
"SMTPD" 3500    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.361"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 354 OK, send."
"SMTPD" 4700    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.363"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 Queued (0.000 seconds)"
"SMTPD" 2636    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.363"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 2636    618 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.364"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.598"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 220 ssl0.ovh.net player772"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.598"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: EHLO mysite.com"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.602"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 250-player772.ha.ovh.net[nl]250-SIZE 104850000[nl]250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN[nl]250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN[nl]250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES[nl]250 8BITMIME"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.603"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: AUTH LOGIN"
"SMTPC" 2724    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.607"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
"SMTPC" 2724    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.607"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: c2VydmVyQG1vZHN6b21iaWVzLm92aA=="
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.611"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.612"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: ***"
"SMTPC" 2724    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.628"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful"
"SMTPC" 2724    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.628"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: ***"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.635"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 250 2.1.0 Ok"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.635"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: RCPT TO:<receiver@web.de>"
"SMTPC" 2636    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.646"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 250 2.1.5 Ok"
"SMTPC" 2636    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.647"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: DATA"
"SMTPC" 2636    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.651"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>"
"SMTPC" 2636    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.652"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: [nl]."
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.699"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6126F74008D"
"SMTPC" 4576    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.700"   "213.186.33.20" "SENT: QUIT"
"SMTPC" 2636    631 "2017-07-05 11:42:22.704"   "213.186.33.20" "RECEIVED: 221 2.0.0 Bye"
```

I'm using hMailServer on Windows and I didn't change anything.

SPF records are setup correctly, but only answers work..

Comment: Looks like there in no problem between your server and relay.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending a new email what the log is saying? Do you see an attempt? Do you get a bounce back email with an error code?

From your description it sounds like a dns issue, like it cannot fetch the correct MX Records for other domains. Login directly to the server and see if it can resolve normally the domains you are sending to.